# Create Tag to Remote Repository using Cake Build

Tags: git, cakebuild

I am committing and pushing a project into remote using a Cake Build task:

```
GitAddAll(".");  

GitCommit(".", authorName, authorEmail, message); 

GitTag(".", version);   

GitPush(".", username, password, "master);
```

The files are being committed to local repository and pushed to remote.

And the tag is being created in local repository but **is not being created in remote**.

How can I create the tag in remote repository, e.g. Github?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as I posted in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185169/how-to-push-tag-to-bitbucket-git-repository-in-bamboo-from-cake-build-task), if your solution folder under source control

```
#addin "Cake.Git"
var solutionFolder = "./";
var versionTag = "someTag";

Task("Default")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        GitTag(solutionFolder, versionTag);
        GitPushRef(solutionFolder, gitUser, gitPassword, "origin", versionTag); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Push tags explicitly. Or configure `push.followTags = true`.

Comment: I think it's `GitPush(".", username, password, version);`

Comment: I did not find such a method? Only one with username, password and branch

Comment: And where do you set FollowTags to true?

Comment: I think GitPush should push any ref: commit ID, branch or tag. If not try [GitPushRef](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/FB8D8875). In command line it's `git config push.followTags true`.